# parsing number with boost spirit qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm parsing a grammar using boost spirit and all the complex parts are working great; however, I'm trying to accept numeric variables and I can't seem to get them to parse properly. I don't want to do anything with the numbers except store them as strings but I can't seem to get a string parser that matches a generic number to work.

Here is code that shows the problem:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> testVec;
    testVec.push_back("25.16");
    testVec.push_back("2516");
    std::string result;
    std::string::const_iterator it, endIt;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        it = testVec[i].begin();
        endIt = testVec[i].end();
        result.clear();

        std::cout << "test" << i << "a: ";
        bool r = qi::phrase_parse(
            it,
            endIt,
            +qi::digit >> -(qi::string(".") >> +qi::digit),
            qi::space,
            result
        );

        if (!r || it != endIt)
        {
            std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }

        it = testVec[i].begin();
        endIt = testVec[i].end();
        result.clear();

        std::cout << "test" << i << "b: ";
        r = qi::phrase_parse(
            it,
            endIt,
            +qi::digit >> (qi::string(".") >> +qi::digit),
            qi::space,
            result
        );

        if (!r || it != endIt)
        {
            std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << result << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
test0a: 25.
test0b: 25.16
test1a: 2516
test1b: failed
```

The second approach is behaving as expected but simply making the decimal part optional changes the result to exclude the numbers after the decimal point.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The reason for wanting to do this is that I'm parsing one grammar to translate into a slightly different grammar. Obviously, both treat numbers the same so I don't care what the number is, just that it is well formed.

Comment: Congratulations on a very well-written first question. If only everyone would put in the effort to give the correct detail and ask a clear question.

Comment: Another possible alternative could be: `qi::raw[qi::double_]` (maybe `qi::as_string[qi::raw[qi::double_]]`). This matches a double, ignores its attribute, and "returns" an iterator range from the beginning of the double until the end. This range is converted (implicitly or explicitly depending on which you use) to a string.

Comment: Why are you parsing a number into a string? I'd strongly suggest `qi::raw [ qi::lexeme [ +qi::digit >> -('.' >> +qi::digit) ] ]` - note the use of `lexeme` ***(!!!)*** or, indeed the `qi::double_` parser as suggested by @cv_and_he (See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d173afd62f2ad74)**)

Comment: @cv_and_he This is a good workaround for my problem which seems most likely to be a spirit issue in boost 1.46.1. If you'd like to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Casey Thanks! I've read enough questions and answers to understand how to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @sehe Sorry, I left out why I would want to do this. I'm parsing one grammar to translate into a slightly different grammar. Obviously, both treat numbers the same so I don't care what the number is, just that it is well formed. My actual code does use lexeme but I left it out of this example because it didn't seem to effect the result.

Comment: To rctaylor: I'm sure @sehe will be able to write a better answer on the subject.

Comment: @cv_and_he Though I don't have too much time :/ I suppose I'd be interested in the YX-problem here. It's always a bit smelly if you go and duct-tape an existing parser onto "slightly" different grammars (smells like a PHP situation). If the original parser was in Spirit, I'd prefer to make it support two versions. Otherwise, [`seek` and `advance`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components.html) could be enormous accelerators (i.c.w. `raw[]`)

Comment: @sehe I'm using two tools which I have no control over. The first outputs LTL and the second takes LTL as input. However, they speak slightly different dialects. A lot of it is simple substitution (e.g. ! => ~) but the first supports xor while the second does not. Translating xor into & and | requires a fairly complete understanding of the semantics and thus I am left parsing the entire LTL string. It has actually gone quite smoothly (I finished today) but for this one issue which, as I said, seems to be an issue with the old version of Spirit I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a problem with your boost spirit version ? Here's my output of your program:

```
$ ./a.exe
test0a: 25.16
test0b: 25.16
test1a: 2516
test1b: failed
```

It is a result I would expect.

And [here is an online compile/run of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5687a31864bcc1e8)

Comment: You may be right. I'm using boost 1.46.1, gcc 4.6.3, and c++98. I configured the online compiler for gcc 4.6 & c++98 but didn't find a way to use an older boost (it is using 1.55). I'll try to update and see if that fixes it.